# jQuery runs one time in IE but works fine in other browsers(opera,chrome,mozilla)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

First of all I'm just a newbie in jQuery (generally speaking in web).

I've seen this question before but I don't get what the solution is.

I have this script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnbackwrd").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.get("/backward.php");
      return null;
   });
});
</script>
```

In /backward.php I have another script (in python) which runs in background when I press the button.

What should I add to make it work more than one time in IE11?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see anything wrong off hand (other than using the old `.click` instead of `.on('click',` syntax).  If it's running once and then failing after that, it could be a javascript error that then kills javascript execution.  It could even be occurring elsewhere in the script.  What does the console output in IE when you try to run it and press the button multiple times?

Comment: Console doesn't output anything.
BTW: When I enter in console mode, it works...

Comment: You will need to make use of the network tab in IE11 and see if it is making the call to `backward.php` more than once. Press F12, go to Network tab, click the green "Play" button in the top-left or press F5, and now initiate the AJAX call. Also, not sure why you have `return null;` but you can safely remove it.